# Should a RESTful Content Provider use SyncAdapter?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-contentprovider, restful-url, android-syncadapter

I have a custom content provider and sync adapter which work fine but I am unclear on best practice to initiate async requests to the server. For example, when a client makes a query request to the content provider it queries the local data db - now it needs to check for server content.

Which of these two ways is recommended for the server requests?

1) kick off direct async requests  inside the content provider to the server for more content
or, given I have a syncadapter,
2) make a ContentResolver.requestSync(... inside the content provider to achieve this indirectly?

It seems like (1) would end up implementing (2) but I haven't come across examples where sync adapters are used from within the content provider. The UI is driven through cursor adapters and observers so it would be very helpful to have conviction about how server syncs happen!

THanks